# The operator+ is undefined for the argument type(s) double boolean

Tags: java

```
1.public class Application 
2.{ 
3.  public static void main(String[] args) 
4.    {
5.    int a = 1;
6.    short b = 0;
7.    long c = 34;
8.  
9.    float d = 5.6f;
10.   double e = 3.65;
11. 
12.   char f = 'A';
13. 
14.   boolean g = true;
15. 
16.   byte h = 126;
17.  
18.   System.out.println(a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h);
19.  }  
20.}
```

Line 18, in eclipse, is showing the error

> "The operator+ is undefined for the argument type(s) double boolean"

I just don't want to add them. I just want to display them with this output :

```
10345.63.65Atrue126
```

Comment: what result would you expect to get with this operation: `3 + true`? Hint: in java that makes no sense

Comment: What does 10 + true equal to?

Comment: Hey then tell me how to print 10245.63.65Atrue126

Comment: That what you were supposed to ask in the "question" part

Comment: i don't want to add all these . I just want to display all of them

Comment: okay i have added . Now guys help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java, a boolean by itself isn't treated like a number, unlike Python where `True` is 1 and `False` is 0.

If you want this type of behavior, you can convert boolean `g` with `int i = g ? 1 : 0;`

EDIT:
I misunderstood your question -- I see that you want to concatenate them, not add them. A good way to do this is with `StringBuilder`:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append(a);
sb.append(b);
sb.append(c);
// ...etc...
String str = sb.toString();
```

Comment: If you read the comments, you’ll see this isn’t what OP wanted.

Comment: hey is string builder is a built in class in java ? can you explain that ?

Comment: Yes, it is located in the `java.lang` package. You will need to import it: `import java.lang.StringBuilder;` Note that it is an Object, not a primitive like `int` or `boolean`.

Comment: can you tell me what is a object ?

Comment: I'd recommend reading up on the Java tutorials. Here's one on objects: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/object.html

Answer (score 0):

To concatenate multiple variable to a string, simply start by adding an empty string.

```
System.out.println("" + a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h);
```

How do that make sense?

In java, adding something to a string convert this "something" to its string format.

Without adding a string, it's just a bunch of figures and "+" symbols, and that's basic maths.

Comment: how would that make sense ? I mean why we have to do that ? Thanks for you reply

Comment: I got thtat man . i am new to stack flow . how can i add you to my favorite or is there any option in stackoverflow to  make you my friend ? thanks

Comment: On stackoverflow, you can't add someone as a contact but you can: 1) vote for answers with the arrows on the left part. 2) accept an answer to your question with the greenish check mark on the left.  [https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Hey do I need to add that something  only at the start of the string or can i add it anywhere ,like in the middle or in the end

Comment: "In java, adding something to a string convert this "something" to its string format."

For future searchers, this is called type coercion.

Answer (score 0):

see [jls](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18):

> The operators + and - are called the additive operators.
>
> **If the type of either operand of a + operator is String, then the
>   operation is string concatenation.**
>
> Otherwise, the type of each of the operands of the + operator must be
>   a type that is convertible (§5.1.8) to a primitive **numeric type**, or a
>   compile-time error occurs.

`boolean` is not a numberic type, so you get this compile error.

You can add an empty string at the end of the statement, the result will be converted to string:

```
System.out.println(a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h + "");
```